# Magento 1 get all checkout child's block on ajax request

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, blocks, ajax, custom-template

I create an action that will return to checkout page when I called it.
My code is,

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('opc/wrapper')->setTemplate('opc/wrapper.phtml')->toHtml();
```

But it shows an empty template of checkout without shipping method or payment method.

How can I fix it or improve my code?

Comment: Please elaborate further - Define empty shipping method or payment method.

Very difficult from this snippet to understand the desired results.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/Hs9Owsb.png @elfling